# Where can I find the source code for mmap?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Kernel 2.6.24.6

I'm writing a syscall interposer. I'd like to interpose mmap, but need to copy and paste the code up to the actualy system call, methinks. I can't find that code to paste? Where is this thing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked in the sources of the applicable libc?

Comment: aha! Went in there are found something called mmap.c - but I don't see the definition of mmap(mmap_ag_struct* arg) like  I expected...

Comment: You may be finding a stub implementation rather than the arch-specific real one.  Also - from the man page: Since kernel 2.4, this system call has been superseded by mmap2(2).  Nowadays, the glibc mmap() wrapper function invokes mmap2(2) with a suitably adjusted value for offset.

Comment: Why not just call `glibc`'s `mmap()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the kernel can't actually provide functions in your program, the calls into the application VDSO are enclosed in the libc implementation you're using. Most likly, you're using GNU libc, for which you can find the sources [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/).

Comment: The premise here is not quite accurate.  While it is customary and portable to use the libc wrappers, coding up direct syscall invocations is entirely possible. So in fact the kernel can actually provide functions to a program, provided you work with the kernel's calling convention.  To think about it another way, libc is just a re-usable program component.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I understand that. What I ment, is that if you don't link to `libc`, you can't just say `mmap2(...)`. Also, you don't even have to know the exact ABI -- at least on x86 and x86-64 -- take a look at the new Linux VDSO with syscall code.

Answer (score 3):

The [mmap(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) C function is just doing a [syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). You might find that [MUSL Libc](http://musl-libc.org/) code is eeasier to read in its [mmap.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/mman/mmap.c) file, which wraps the syscall (perhaps using `mmap2`). The actual processing of syscalls is done inside the kernel.

The [Linux Assembly Howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) is explaining how the syscalls are actually done. See also the [x86-64 ABI spec](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf).

Comment: Except that on modern linux, the mmap() syscall is either deprecated or missing, with the functionality emulated in userspace using the more flexible mmap2() syscall.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a kernel source and look at (Kernel Source)/drivers/char/mem.c

There you can find a simple implementation for mmap with the prototype:

```
static int mmap_mem(struct file *file, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
```

At some point, mmap() should call remap_pfn_range() to remap kernel memory to user space.

I think this is the simplest implementation of mmap() for a driver, but you can also look at other driver codes to find out about their implementation of mmap(). You should look for the following structure in the driver code:

```
static const struct file_operations mem_fops = {
    .llseek     = memory_lseek,
    .read       = read_mem,
    .write      = write_mem,
    .mmap       = mmap_mem,         // Function implementing mmap
    .open       = open_mem,
    .get_unmapped_area = get_unmapped_area_mem,
};
```